# Cannon rotation (horizontally and vertically) when my finger touches the screen in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently, when I touch my mobile screen the player's aim moves horizontally and vertically. When the player's aim moves I want the cannon to also rotate horizontally and vertically. I tried a different method but was not successful.

```
void Update() 
{

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            aim.transform.position = new Vector3(aim.transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * 0.15f, aim.transform.position.y, aim.transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.y * 0.15f);
        }
        Vector3 direction = aim.transform.position - firepoint.position;
        Vector3 groundDirection = new Vector3(direction.x, direction.y, direction.z);
        // aim.transform.position = (hit.point + Vector3.up);
        Vector3 targetpos = new Vector3(direction.magnitude, direction.y, direction.magnitude);
        targetpos.z = 0;
        float angle;
        float height = targetpos.y + targetpos.magnitude / 2f;
        height = Mathf.Max(0.01f, height);
        float v0;
        float time;

        calculatePathwithHeight(targetpos, height, out v0, out angle, out time);
        initialVelocity = v0;
        
        cannon.transform.localEulerAngles =new Vector3(initialVelocity,initialVelocity,initialVelocity);
        cannon.transform.rotation=Quaternion.LookRotation(aim.transform.position);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Movement(groundDirection.normalized, v0, angle, time));
            mainCamera.GetComponent<cameraFollow>().enabled = true;
            FindObjectOfType<cameraFollow>().zoomIn = true;
            FindObjectOfType<cameraFollow>().zoomOut = false;
        }
    }
}
```